# PHP - Block External API Calls

Tags: php, api, block

I've created an API in my site in PHP

Now I want to protect it because I don't want that other sites and/or users can call it from a website that it isn't mine

The calls can be made only from my site

How can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: There is multiple way to do that, You could simply create a hardcoded password that you have to supply with the credential  Or have only static IPs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use this at the start of your API

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != '127.0.0.1'){
    die;
}
```

It will kill any API attempts that aren't being called from your server.

**Edit**

Or if you want users to be able to call the API, you can gave them an API key, that you will store in your database.

Ex.

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
$key = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['key']);
$search = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE api_key = '$key'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($search)==0){
    // kill the request
    die;
}
else{
    // Allow the request and do your business
}
```

Comment: the problem is that the users can call the API (it's a registration confirm) and the $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] tag needs to match site's IP, not user's IP, in your suggestion...

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is your site's server ip, not the user's. Why not just make an API key?

Comment: I've edited my answer to show you a way of accepting API keys.