# Secure Php execution on server

Tags: php, apache, security

I have a php script which updates a database. I want to be sure that no one else can call my script remotely and execute it.

I tried this code but it did not work, the refer was always empty because I use https connection.

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTPS_REFERER'], 'linkedfilm.com') == false) 
{
    exit();
}
```

The server is Apache server.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe design a [RBAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control). User must be logged in and of a certain role (admin for example).

Comment: Are you looking for this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51129624/protecting-sql-server-for-private-usage/51129788#51129788 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello [Daina Hodges](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5615853/daina-hodges),

You got a few options to secure this .php script.

1. You can secure this script by moving it into another directory outside of your DOCUMENT_ROOT
2. You can add the [.htaccess](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html)
3. You can allow [only local ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36580917/php-block-external-api-calls)

Comment: or you can allow [only command-line access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942435/how-to-make-a-php-file-run-able-only-through-cli-mode)

Answer (score 1):

You could use .htaccess and put your script in a password protected directory.

Or you could use some sort of login and authentication routines on your site so you can login and access that script.

Or you could pass a 'secret' key with you call to the script, quick and dirty

```
if( $_GET['secret'] != "mysecret" ) exit();
```